# Auth by Google web authentication broker

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I'm faced with problem to auth in google web authentication broker. i think something wronge with this scope https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthLogin. Yesterday it work good but now Google change something or not support this scope. What new scope for auth by web authentication broker.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DalmTo if I add  "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthLogin" to scopes -> google says that this is "invalid_scope" but before that for 9 mouth all was ok :(

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Regression: OAuth Invalid Scope (Google Hangouts)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314580/regression-oauth-invalid-scope-google-hangouts).